# Enable UDP protocol in Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: rdp, udp, windows-10

I have a computer to which I am connecting via RDP. However, using the default Windows applications (Remote Desktop Connection) probably will not use UDP port. By clicking the connection information getting only 'The quality of the connection to the remote computer is good'. It seems to me that when combined UDP should be written again: 'UDP is enabled'. How to unlock RDP connection via UDP? Until now, only added to the firewall exception. Didn't help.

Comment: is the remote computer sitting behind NAT?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to use UDP for RDP?

Comment: What Windows OS and Edition are you connecting **FROM** and **TO**?

Comment: Daniel Widrick, yes, the remote computer sitting behind NAT. womble, because I heard that using UDP for RDP is better performance than TCP. joeqwerty, on the local and remote computer I have installed Windows 10 Enterprise x64

Comment: I'm using WinServer 2019 and the client is within the same network. I've changed the register by "Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:/Software/Policies/Microsoft/Windows NT/Terminal Services/Client' 'fClientDisableUDP' 0". Still not work.